# AngularFire collection: Update/replace query path with a new path

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I have a service that has an `AngularFirestore.collection` Observable.

```
...
export class AppFirestoreService {
  public rootCategories$: Observable<Category[]>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.rootCategories$ = this.afs.collection<Category>(`categories`).snapshotChanges()
    .pip(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `rootCategories$` is *subscribed* in several components, and the **path** I need update to another one.

So I thought of **replacing** the `rootCategories` variable with a new `Observable`, but I'm not sure if the old `Observable` will be cleared of the memory.
Is there is a way to make the path as a variable without create another `Observable` and leaving the old one (or its subscription) existing in memory.
Thanks

Can you please guide me to correct way to solve this problem.

Editing to clarify:
How to change the current Observable `rootCategories$` with new path, and make old subscription notified with the new emitted value?

Comment: so you want to share rootCategories$?

Comment: @FanCheung it's already shared, but I want to change results coming from Observable, using another path.

Comment: you can use rootCategories to compose a new stream for that purpose and not affecting the existing subscription.  myNewStream=$this.rootCategories$.pipe(.....)

Comment: or are you looking to change the collection path dynamically?

Comment: set it up as a function `rootCategories=(path)=>this.afs.collection(path).snapshotChanges()`

Comment: @FanCheung I thought of something like this, but are you sure this will not leave old observable in memory?

Comment: I mean this kinda usage should be avoided, it is a strange requirement, if.the path is going to change you should have these in a seperate class proprety, why limit it to rootCategories$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210437/discussion-between-nomad-and-fan-cheung).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, unless someone points out it has some drawbacks on it.

The combination of `BehaviorSubject` and mergeMap, solved my problem. The path is emmitted and controlled from a `BehaviorSubject` and the `AngularFirestore.collection` is returned with the new path:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
@Injectable(...)
export class AppFirestoreService {
  public rootCategories$: Observable<CategoryId[]>;
  private pathBS = new BehaviorSubject<string>('categories');

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.rootCategories$ = this.pathBS.asObservable().pipe(
      mergeMap(path => {
        return this.afs.collection<Category>(path).snapshotChanges()...
      })
    );
  }

  setNewPath(path: string) {
    this.pathBS.next(path);
  }
}
```